# JavaScript variable with no initial value returns null in one case and undefined in another

Tags: javascript

So I am learning JavaScript and tested the code below:

```
var name;
console.log( name );
```

returns `null`

```
var c;
console.log( c );
```

returns `undefined`

why is this?

Documentation states: `A variable declared using the var statement with no initial value specified has the value undefined.`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Declaring_variables

Any references to official documentation would be great!

Comment: Both should return `undefined`. Try posting a demo to reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I was testing in Node, where you get reference error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're doing this in a browser, it's because `name` *already* exists in the browser environment (it's the name of the window). So the `var name` is a no-op. But see below, the `null` bit surprises me.

In JavaScript, global variables are actually properties of the global object. The global object is the value `this` has in code at global scope*. In browsers, the global object is the browser's window object for that page, and so it has any properties defined for the Window object. One of those is `name`. (Another is `window`, which is a property the global object has that has a reference back to the global object, so you can use `window` to refer to it even not at global scope.) The global object on browsers is actually quite crowded, as browsers dump properties on it for any element that has an `id` (the property name is the `id`, the value is a reference to the element), there's `forms`, `all` on some browsers, `document`, and a bunch of other stuff.

Outside of browsers, the global object doesn't have any automatic property pointing to it (well, unless the environment adds one), and won't have browser-specific things on it (but may have things specific to whatever environment you're in).

---

* Unless you have `"use strict"` at the top of your script, which puts it in strict mode, in which case `this` is `undefined`.

---

About you getting `null` as output from your first example: I find that very surprising; I would have expected `""` (a blank string) or, of course, the name of the window if there is one. Something, somewhere, must be assigning `null` or `"null"` to `name` (either of which make it the string `"null"` on the various browsers I've tried [Chrome, Firefox, IE8, IE11]). You can try it with this page (jsFiddle and such give the window they run things in names, so I can't use them for this example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    display("[before] typeof name: " + typeof name);
    display("[before] name: " + name);

    display("Doing <code>name = null;</code>");
    name = null; // Gets coerced to string "null"

    display("[after] typeof name: " + typeof name);
    display("[after] name: " + name);

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Where can I test pure JavaScript without these types of things occurring?

Comment: @samyismyhero: Well, almost any environment is going to have *some* environment-specific stuff it adds to the global object. For instance, NodeJS adds `require`. But I'd say NodeJS will be a much, much cleaner environment than a browser; all *sorts* of things get dumped on the global object in browsers.

Comment: 'no-op' what's that? Google says 'no operation'

Comment: @samyismyhero: Right. Since there's *already* a property on the global object called `name`, the `var name` doesn't do anything. It's a no-op. That's another JavaScript thing: Re-declaring a variable that already exists doesn't do anything (doesn't cause an error, for instance). That's the vague description, but if you're just learning, it's sufficient for now.